# My phone is not saving things (screenshots, download from browser, etc)

Tags: internal-storage, android-10, media-files, sqlite, oneplus-5t

So one day my phone shutdown and when restarted I started to get some issues. Screenshot was not working saying that there was no space left. Gallery had no images/videos at all. File manager was not opening properly. I started to dig up and was able to get an stack trace:

```
## Issue explanation (write below this line)


## Exception
* _User Action:_ UI Error
* _Request:_ Application crash
* _Version:_ 3.5.9
* _OS:_ Linux Android 10 - 29
* _Device:_ OnePlus5
* _Model:_ ONEPLUS A5000
* _Product:_ OnePlus5

Crash log


java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:184)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:437)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:962)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:890)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:846)
    at com.amaze.filemanager.asynchronous.asynctasks.LoadFilesListTask.listMediaCommon(LoadFilesListTask.java:336)
    at com.amaze.filemanager.asynchronous.asynctasks.LoadFilesListTask.listVideos(LoadFilesListTask.java:324)
    at com.amaze.filemanager.asynchronous.asynctasks.LoadFilesListTask.doInBackground(LoadFilesListTask.java:165)
    at com.amaze.filemanager.asynchronous.asynctasks.LoadFilesListTask.doInBackground(LoadFilesListTask.java:68)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
```

Could be corruption on file db? I have one app called "Files" which I can check, and I see all files there. I can take pictures/videos, record voice etc, so that doesn't seem the problem.

I think the issue is related to indexation of those things, I've tried re-scan with several apps, but none worked (media re-scan, rescan sd, etc)

I don't want to factory reset at the moment so I'm looking for an alternative solution (maybe a path to where is the db, so I can delete files, or an app that can help me to re-index things [if is the case], or system access to assess the issue)

Comment: Have you tried to manually clear the app data of the Android Media Store app? That forces a rescan and a defect old database is deleted (only the database is deleted not the media files).

Comment: Well I have no Android Media Store app, only gallery, file manager and some relateds, anyway I've cleared app data from most applications also cache and rescan didn't worked as supposed to. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Every Android since Android 5 device has an Android Media Store app. It is a system app.

Comment: Ok, i've found media storage, cleared data/cache, still getting same issue :/